# Как убрать с сайта вертикальную полосу прокрутки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но чтобы при этом *скролл* работал как обычно?

К *body*, например, можно применить `overflow-y:hidden`, но, естественно, *скролл* перестает работать.

Comment: Есть куча плагинов для этого, можно сделать самому - ловить нужные события и скролить контент

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/53rr1ufo/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Привет, если речь идет именно о body то ему необходимо присвоить значение overflow-y:hidden а уже в body вставить div с контентом, например вот таким образом [клик](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html) или [клик](http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/) там уже скрыть скролл у diva без последствий не работы прокрутки, если речь идет о простом div(например, меню):

Допустим есть левый блок меню. В этом блоке идет нумерованный список пунктов, на 100 примерно.

```css
div.LeftScrollBlock{
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
div.parent{
  border-right:1px solid grey;
  width: 184px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="LeftScrollBlock">
<ul>
    <li>ссылка-1</li>
    <li>ссылка-2</li>
    <li>ссылка-3</li>
    <li>ссылка-4</li>
    <li>ссылка-5</li>
    <li>ссылка-6</li>
    <li>ссылка-7</li>
    <li>ссылка-8</li>
    <li>ссылка-9</li>
    <li>ссылка-10</li>
    <li>ссылка-11</li>
    <li>ссылка-12</li>
    <li>ссылка-13</li>
    <li>ссылка-14</li>
    <li>ссылка-15</li>
    <li>ссылка-16</li>
    <li>ссылка-17</li>
    <li>ссылка-18</li>
    <li>ссылка-19</li>
    <li>ссылка-20</li>
    <li>ссылка-21</li>
    <li>ссылка-22</li>
    <li>ссылка-23</li>
    <li>ссылка-24</li>
    <li>ссылка-25</li>
    <li>ссылка-26</li>
    <li>ссылка-27</li>
    <li>ссылка-28</li>
    <li>ссылка-29</li>
    <li>ссылка-30</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Предположим, так. С шириной и кроссбраузерностью разберёшься сам. Ещё, выделением текста можно проскроллить вправо.

А вообще, скрывать скролл - это плохая идея.

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.<p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.
```

Вариант без calc с использованием фиксированного позиционирования. Решает проблему с горизонтальной прокруткой при выделении.

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.<p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.
```

Ещё вариант для хромиумовов:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.<p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.    <p>Здравствуйте. Можно ли убрать, скрыть на сайте методами css или javascript вертикальную прокрутку, но , чтобы при этом скролл работал как обычно? К body, например, можно применить overflow-y:hidden, но естественно скролл перестает работать.
```

Comment: Предлагаемая праывка от @ИльгамКаримов: p.s calc() не поддерживается моб.устройствами и работает в ie с 9 версии.
Только CSS3. [Поддержка браузеров](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) не полная.

Comment: @ИльгамКаримов, проголосовал за отклонение правки. Про мобильные браузеры - не совсем верно. На MDN утверждается, что там оно есть, но с багами, на caniuse, что есть. Про возможные проблемы с кроссбраузерностью я предупредил. Там скорее будут проблемы с разной шириной полосы прокрутки на разных устройствах. А саму идею можно реализовать и без calc: например, при помощи абсолютного или фиксированного позиционирования. Кстати, оно же ещё и скроллиться не будет. Пожалуй, допишу в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Скрыть или изменить дизайн полосы прокрутки можно с помощью js плагинов которых теперь есть большой выбор например: [9 вариантов](http://www.sitehere.ru/izmenyaem-vid-polosy-prokrutki-v-brauzere-chast-1).

Comment: Завтра сайт закроют и пользы от вашего ответа будет не больше чем от моего комментария. Будет лучше, если вы приведете небольшой пример.

Comment: У меня касперский вообще его заблокировал....